# Remove div with class without content from multimple nested places

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
<div class="stuff">
    <div class="removeme">
        <div class="iamfree">
            iamfree
            <div class="removeme">
                <div class="ishouldbefreetoo">
                    ishouldbefreetoo
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want:

```
    <div class="stuff">
        <div class="iamfree">
            iamfree
                <div class="ishouldbefreetoo">
                    ishouldbefreetoo
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Tried the unwrap() function from jQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/adyz/7d947wja/

Also, cloned elements act strange with unwrap.

Comment: You have unclosed divs in both before and after?

Comment: Your HTML in invalid...

Comment: @Dan no, check the fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) on the contents of the elements to be removed.

```
$('.removeme').contents().unwrap()
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/c3k3xgmx/)

> Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM,
>   leaving the matched elements in their place.

Comment: Hi Arun, can you please check my fiddle and update there? I am not sure why my textarea does not get things right. Also, any idea why the clone method does not work?

Comment: thanks alot. I think you should add the link in your answer and maybe some details about why you needed to add the array index and so on for other people in search of this.

Comment: also, I am looking in your fiddle and I see that if you unwrap in HTML directly the text is removed... but for clone it looks fine.